# Does drowning count as a condition?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, conditions, underwater, breathing

So I know we are going to some kind of underwater place next session. I was wondering if the bard could use *Lesser Restoration* to "fix" the drowning "condition". That is, if it counts as one.

Comment: What rules are you using for drowning? Are you using the [suffocating rules](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/adventuring#Suffocating)?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### No, drowning isn't a condition

Conditions, as a mechanical thing, are only those listed in **Appendix A: Conditions** of the [Player's Handbook](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/phb/appendix-a-conditions) or [Basic Rules](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/appendix-a-conditions). Drowning is not a condition listed there. Instead, death due to lack of air is described by the rules for [suffocation](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/adventuring#Suffocating), which does not specifically require being underwater, just being unable to breathe, and doesn't impose any conditions - you simply drop straight to dying if you hold your breath too long.

Additionally, even if drowning was a condition that was imposed by suffocating underwater, *[lesser restoration](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/lesser-restoration)* would not be able to fix it, since it states that:

> You touch a creature and can end either one disease or one condition afflicting it. The condition can be blinded, deafened, paralyzed, or poisoned.

Drowning is not in the list of conditions that *lesser restoration* can end.

Answer (score 24):

#### *Lesser restoration* can't cure drowning

You can see the [full list of conditions](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/appendix-a-conditions),  in the basic rules. Drowning is not included in this list and thus is not a condition.

However, even if drowning was a condition, *lesser restoration* still wouldn't help you. It does not heal all conditions, just a [specific subset of conditions](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/lesser-restoration):

> You touch a creature and can end either one disease or one condition afflicting it. **The condition can be blinded, deafened, paralyzed, or poisoned.**

If you need a magical solution for drowning then the spell *water breathing* is one of the games more efficient solutions (affects 10 people for a whole day).

Comment: Even if it could, it still wouldn't help you to breath underwater. The same way Lesser Restoration can't make you see in darkness, despite "a creature in a heavily obscured area effectively suffers from the blinded condition" and blinded condition can be cured by Lesser Restoration.

Comment: @enkryptor: I suppose a rules lawyer could argue that Lesser Restoration technically _can_ cure the blinded condition resulting from being in darkness — but the condition then gets immediately re-imposed, since it's still dark. But that'd be just silly. :P

Comment: @IlmariKaronen the same with breathing underwater, I guess

Comment: @enkryptor I entirely agree, there's a number of levels on which this doesn't work. I could add that in, but sometimes the simplest answer's the best answer.